# copy from spreadsheet to another spreadsheet with dynamic title

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm currently working on a project where to I need to copy data from one specific sheet in a spreadsheet to another spreadsheet with a dynamic title ( text with date).
moving the data with ID or by name is ok but with a freshly created spreadsheet seems tuff.
all the function will be in the same app script:
creation
copy

```
function titleAsDate() {

  var currentDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT+8", "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss")
  SpreadsheetApp.create("Report of the " + currentDate)
}

function copyWithValues() {
  let spreadSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  let sourceSheet = spreadSheet.getSheetByName('Sources');
  
  let sourceRange = sourceSheet.getDataRange();
  let sourceValues = sourceRange.getValues();
  
  let rowCount = sourceValues.length;
  let columnCount = sourceValues[0].length;
  
  let targetSheet = spreadSheet.getSheetById('Target');
  let targetRange = targetSheet.getRange(1, 1, rowCount, columnCount);
  
  targetRange.setValues(sourceValues);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Explanation:

- [SpreadsheetApp.create(name)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#createname) returns a [spreadsheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet) object so you can directly use the output of this function directly without the need of extra code.
- The newly generated spreadsheet will have one sheet with the name `Sheet1` as when you manually create a new spreadsheet file. Therefore, you can use the [sheet.setName(name)](http://setName(name)) function to change the name of the sheet to `Target`. Also this function returns a [sheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet) object (`targetSheet`) which can then be used to set the values.

### Solution:

This is all the code in one function:

```
function copyWithValues() {
  const spreadSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const sourceSheet = spreadSheet.getSheetByName('Sources');
  const sourceRange = sourceSheet.getDataRange();
  const sourceValues = sourceRange.getValues();
  
  const currentDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT+8", "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss"); // new code
  const targetSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.create("Report of the " + currentDate); // new code
  
  let rowCount = sourceValues.length;
  let columnCount = sourceValues[0].length;
  
  let targetSheet = targetSpreadsheet.getSheetByName('Sheet1').setName("Target"); // new code
  let targetRange = targetSheet.getRange(1, 1, rowCount, columnCount);
  
  targetRange.setValues(sourceValues);
}
```

If you want to use `titleAsDate` as a helper function which will be called by `copyWithValues`, then you can use this code and execute only `copyWithValues`:

```
// helper function, used by copyWithValues
function titleAsDate() {
  const currentDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT+8", "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss");
  return SpreadsheetApp.create("Report of the " + currentDate); // new code
}

// main function, you should execute this function
function copyWithValues() {
  const spreadSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const sourceSheet = spreadSheet.getSheetByName('Sources');
  const sourceRange = sourceSheet.getDataRange();
  const sourceValues = sourceRange.getValues();
  
  const targetSpreadsheet = titleAsDate(); // new code
  
  let rowCount = sourceValues.length;
  let columnCount = sourceValues[0].length;
  
  let targetSheet = targetSpreadsheet.getSheetByName('Sheet1').setName("Target"); // new code
  let targetRange = targetSheet.getRange(1, 1, rowCount, columnCount);
  
  targetRange.setValues(sourceValues);
}
```