# Copy filter data from one spreadsheet file to another - Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm currently working on a project where I need to copy data to another google sheet.
let me explain:
I'd created a function where I applied filter by text and it works. But the issue is that I can't copy only the filtered data to another sheet. I'd seen many stack conversations but nothing fit.

here is the code

```
function copyWithValues() {
  const spreadSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const sourceSheet = spreadSheet.getSheetByName('testo');
  const sourceRange = sourceSheet.getDataRange();
  const sourceValues = sourceRange.getValues(); 
  
  const targetSpreadsheet = titleAsDate();
  
  let rowCount = sourceValues.length;
  let columnCount = sourceValues[0].length;
  
  let targetSheet = targetSpreadsheet.getSheetByName('Sheet1').setName("Report");
  let targetRange = targetSheet.getRange(1, 1, rowCount, columnCount);
  
  targetRange.setValues(sourceValues);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Explanation:

The following solution is inspired by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52227279/11225291).

- The latter has one limitation though, it only works for transferring the filter data between sheets of the **same** spreadsheet.

We are going to use the exact same answer to copy the **filter** values from the source sheet and paste them to a temporary sheet `temp_sheet` of the source spreadsheet file.

Then we simply get the values of that temporary file and paste them to **another** spreadsheet file with the regular method of getting and setting the values as you have already implemented in your code.

### Solution:

```
function copyWithValues() {
  const spreadSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const sourceSheet = spreadSheet.getSheetByName('testo');
  const temp_sheet = spreadSheet.insertSheet('temp_sheet');
  const sourceRange = sourceSheet.getFilter().getRange();
  sourceRange.copyTo(
    temp_sheet.getRange('A1'),
    SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_NORMAL,
    false);
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();
  
  const sourceValues = temp_sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  
  const targetSpreadsheet = titleAsDate();
  
  const rowCount = sourceValues.length;
  const columnCount = sourceValues[0].length;
  
  const targetSheet = targetSpreadsheet.getSheetByName('Sheet1').setName("Report");
  const targetRange = targetSheet.getRange(1, 1, rowCount, columnCount);
  targetRange.setValues(sourceValues);
  spreadSheet.deleteSheet(temp_sheet);
}
```

where the helper function `titleAsDate()` is defined as:

```
function titleAsDate() {
  const currentDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT+8", "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss");
  return SpreadsheetApp.create("Report of the " + currentDate);
}
```

based on your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66207247/copy-from-spreadsheet-to-another-spreadsheet-with-dynamic-title).

Comment: In this case, I thought that when the filtered values are directly retrieved, it is not required to use the temporal sheet. For this, this thread might be useful. https://stackoverflow.com/a/66147577 and https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/053d3ebbe76fa7c0b5e80ea9d6396011 But if this was not the direction you and OP want, I apologize.

Comment: @Tanaike thanks for the solution I didn't see it when searched for similar threads. I believe your solution might have better performance, but I think OP will find my approach easier to understand. I might be mistaken of course. I am sure your solution would work a lot better for more data, but for a small dataset I tested the solution above and it worked pretty fast. Feel free to post your answer if you want and I will upvote it of course and support it. :) Thanks also for your answer, I will read it so I can learn a better approach myself :)

Comment: @Marios Thank you for replying. If that information was useful for you and OP as the additional information, I'm glad.